# Can't get this IF statement to work - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that it won't display the page unless the asset belongs to one of the users projects (in order to stop others viewing whatever). For some reason I cannot get this to work, as it is currently rendering the else part when it should be doing rendering the asset.

```
    def show
      @website = Asset.find(params[:id])
      ##Add if statement so only current users can view
      if @website.project_id == current_user.projects.all.each { |s| s.id}
        @website
      else
        render(:action => 'blank')
      end


    end
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: If "an id" == "some array"? Doesn't that seem .. wrong? Also, note that [`#each {block}`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each) *returns the original array object*, as opposed to `#map`, and is generally only used for side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
 def show
   @website = Asset.find(params[:id])

   if current_user.projects.pluck(:id).include?(@website.project_id)
      @website
   else
      render(:action => 'blank')
   end

 end
```

This is much more optimized than what you are trying to achieve.

**The mistake** is `current_user.projects.all.each { |s| s.id}` will return you array of projects. Thus you will never be able to compare the project_id to an array.

Instead you need a array of `Project ids` and then find if your desired `project_id` is included in that array.

### Edit

Going further we can also use something like

```
 def show
   @website = Asset.find(params[:id])

   if current_user.projects.find_by_id(@website.project_id).present?          
      @website
   else
      render(:action => 'blank')
   end

 end
```

This way our desired result is directly fetched from database and we need not to compare or evaluate much.

Comment: `#pluck` (and the intermediate enumerable) can be skipped with [`#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

Comment: Yes. We can. But using pluck is more beificial than any. For any first we will fetch all records and then loop over everything. Pluck will return only id from the database. Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worked like a charm. I edited it just to include the first line again because it was giving me an error without it. But thanks again!